# How to get a list of changsets between two git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I want to see the different changesets between to git repositories.  The repos are related but neither is the direct origin of the other.  In Mercurial, I would just do "hg outgoing *other-repo*" and "hg incoming *other-repo*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the different changesets between two branches in a repo. In git, you'll have a couple extra steps. Go into one of the repos and do the following

```
git remote add other OTHER_REPO
git fetch other
```

Now you can view the differences with one of the following depending on which direction you want to go

```
# Similar to hg outgoing (changes which in your branch not in the remote) 
git log other/BRANCH_NAME..BRANCH_NAME

# Similar to hg incoming (changes in the remote not in your branch)
git log BRANCH_NAME..other/BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: If you got an error message, it doesn't seem to have been posted.

Comment: To clarify `other` can be any name you want. `OTHER_REPO` can be anything you would pass to `git clone` and `BRANCH_NAME` should be the name of the branch you're trying to compare.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to edit my answer and I took too long.  Your solution works.  If you edit your answer to state which is equivalent to "hg incoming" and "hg outgoing" I will accept your answer.

Comment: @StephenRasku Done. You may find [`git-utils`](https://github.com/michaelmior/git-utils) useful. If you put the executables in your path, you'll have `git incoming` and `git outgoing` that work like the commands above but just use the default branch and remote.

Comment: Just noticed my fork is very old. When I forked, some of the commands were broken. It seems the original repo has been updated since, so you may want to check that out.